# use ls command as input for shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hadoop, awk

I have my files in Hadoop file system; I need to run phoenix bulk import over each of them. 
right now my shell script is like this:

> test.sh:

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.jar:/etc/hbase/conf hadoop jar  /usr/lib/phoenix/lib/phoenix/phoenix-1.2.0-client.jar org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool --table NETWORK_HEALTH --input $1
```

The output of `hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp` is :

```
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop  405003334 2016-04-06 15:28 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160210-20160211.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1373330318 2016-04-06 15:28 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160211-20160212.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1303613420 2016-04-06 15:28 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160212-20160213.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1239413840 2016-04-06 15:28 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160214-20160215.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1342998954 2016-04-06 15:28 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160215-20160216.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1248737317 2016-04-06 15:29 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160216-20160217.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1146305115 2016-04-06 15:29 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160217-20160218.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1357281689 2016-04-06 15:29 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160218-20160219.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1113842508 2016-04-06 15:29 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160219-20160220.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1193977572 2016-04-06 15:29 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160220-20160221.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1005786711 2016-04-06 15:30 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160221-20160222.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1159168545 2016-04-06 15:30 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160222-20160223.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1163804889 2016-04-06 15:30 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160223-20160224.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1048950098 2016-04-06 15:30 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160224-20160225.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1251527803 2016-04-06 15:30 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160225-20160226.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1288661897 2016-04-06 15:31 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160226-20160227.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1226833581 2016-04-06 15:31 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160227-20160228.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1245110612 2016-04-06 15:31 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160228-20160229.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1321007542 2016-04-06 15:31 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160229-20160230.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1301010760 2016-04-06 15:31 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160301-20160302.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1121192190 2016-04-06 15:32 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160302-20160303.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1296388727 2016-04-06 15:32 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160303-20160304.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1280975648 2016-04-06 15:32 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160304-20160305.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1264795738 2016-04-06 15:32 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160305-20160306.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1248570281 2016-04-06 15:32 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160306-20160307.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1335704328 2016-04-06 15:33 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160307-20160308.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1246153114 2016-04-06 15:33 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160308-20160309.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1251409839 2016-04-06 15:33 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160309-20160310.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1120439077 2016-04-06 15:33 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160310-20160311.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1151595336 2016-04-06 15:33 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160311-20160312.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1304537932 2016-04-06 15:34 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160312-20160313.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1065020972 2016-04-06 15:34 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160313-20160314.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1237905144 2016-04-06 15:34 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160314-20160315.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1038185956 2016-04-06 15:34 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160315-20160316.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1216670016 2016-04-06 15:35 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160316-20160317.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1139180542 2016-04-06 15:35 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160317-20160318.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop 1052672363 2016-04-06 15:35 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160318-20160319.txt
-rw-r--r--   2 root hadoop  892045686 2016-04-06 15:35 /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160319-20160320.txt
```

When I run below command it's only working for first line:

> hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp |  awk '{print $8}' |
>   xargs sh test.sh

How can I fix it that it runs the test.sh for every file I have in ls output?

Comment: Obligatory warning: [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use process substitution:

```
while read -r _ _ _ _ _ _ _ var8 _; do
   bash ./test.sh "$var8"
done < <(hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp)
```

If you have to use `xargs` then use `-I` option:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp | awk '{print $8}' | xargs -I {} sh test.sh '{}'`
```

Comment: it throws an error for meline 3: syntax error near unexpected token `<',

Comment: Make sure you execute it using `bash` not `sh`

Answer (score 1):

add `-n 1` to your command

```
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/hbase-temp/tmp | awk '{print $8}' | xargs -n 1 sh test.sh
```

Here's the man page document:

```
 -n number
         Set the maximum number of arguments taken from standard input for each invocation of utility.  An invocation of utility will use less than number standard input arguments if the number of bytes accu-
         mulated (see the -s option) exceeds the specified size or there are fewer than number arguments remaining for the last invocation of utility.  The current default value for number is 5000.
```

I have `echo $1`  in my test.sh file and 3 sample lines in input.txt. Test result is:

```
$awk '{print $8}' input.txt |xargs  -n1 sh test.sh                                                                                                                                 Wed  6 Apr 16:31:14 2016
/tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160210-20160211.txt
/tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160211-20160212.txt
/tmp/hbase-temp/tmp/nodeHealth20160212-20160213.txt
```

Comment: your solution worked too, yet I accepted the @anubhava since he answered it first.